# How not to be confined into content area... full size web app on Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.1

I am currently creating an Intranet ERP application that will integrate an already existing corporate Joomla 3.1 based web site.

The extension i made so far only has one default controller php file and everything is made using a JavaScript UI framework. (i.e. jqWidgets) So i am not using model, views, helpers.

The other php files are there to respond to the client side interface AJAX requests.

So i mainly need Joomla for the user authentication and session control features but i dont want it to confine my extensions output to the content area... i need the entire document surface... no menu, no module columns, no nothing !

Can it be done ?

Comment: component.php in the template will show only the component's output add &tmpl=component to the urls

Comment: You're my new best friend Patrick...   Thanks !

Comment: you can also just edit the templates index.php to look like component.php so that you dont have to add the &tmpl=component to the urls.

Comment: Yes i thought of creating a custom template with only one placeholder for the component's output but i was sure there was some other way... I guess it was the best way afterall.

Comment: Hey i am new here and totally lost.... how do i vote up your Comment so that it becomes the official answer ???

Comment: i made my comments an answer you can vote up/accept that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways

1. component.php in the template will show only the component's output add `&tmpl=component` to your urls
2. Make a custom template that only outputs the component

> ```
> <html>
>   <head>
>           <!-- put what scripts stylesheets you need etc//-->
>   </head>
>   <body>
>           <jdoc:include type="component" />
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: Second solution is better IMHO